# In cassandra udf i am parsing date as saumya.text2dt('2019-01-16 13:10:44.000') and output is like 2019-10-16 07:30:00.000000+0000

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

My Cassandra User defined function:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text2dt ( input text )
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS timestamp 
LANGUAGE java
AS '
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SSS.SSS");
try{
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(input);
return date;  
}catch(Exception e){
return null;
}      
';
```

My query is :-

```
select saumya.text2dt('2019-01-16 13:10:44.000') from system.local;
```

Output :-

### saumya.text2dt('2019-01-16 13:10:44.000')

```
       2019-10-16 07:30:00.000000+0000
```